# ConsumerRecord returns Null value

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have started learning apache kafka newly and trying to create a sample application project of POS. In this project i am facing an issue with ConsumerRecord object. this object is providing me null value corresponding to value attribute, where i am expecting object of type PosInvoice.class.

**codebase is at below location:-**
https://github.com/romitmodi/pos-simulator/blob/master/src/main/java/learning/kafka/tutorial/pos/simulator/InvoiceConsumer.java

Not sure what i am doing incorrect. please can someone advise.

Thanks a alot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the "return" statement on line no 31 of learning/kafka/tutorial/pos/simulator/deserializers/JsonDeserializer.java